# How to force the browser to always show images in full size?

Tags: browser, images

When I load some pages that have just an image, the browser always tries to fit the image to the current window size, and to view full size, I have to click on the image with the magnifying glass.  This happens with both chrome and firefox.

How can I force these pages to always show at full size, or at least default to showing at full size?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Tampermonkey script to run on all data:image url pages and grab the image's HTML5 [naturalWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth) and [naturalHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight) and override the image's width and height properties on load and window resize, or set img inline css width/height !important, as the browser is setting these properties.

Comment: thanks, but I'm hoping there is a browser config buried somewhere, vs having to develop a custom solution